# UItextfield editing and response

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

hi problem is I have set the UItextfield to limited characters but it works fine with the iPhone keyboard and my Mac keyboard but it passes that limits when I use the numbers on my UIView

the limit code:

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!

    @IBAction func Botton1(_ sender: UIButton) {

        textField1.text = textField1.text! + String (sender.tag)
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if range.length + range.location > (textField1.text?.count)!{

            return false
        }
        let NewLength = (textField1.text?.count)! + string.count - range.length

        return NewLength < 4
    }


}
```

Comment: because when you are having custom keyboard, the delegate methods do not get called. try calling shouldChangeCharactersInRange explicitly and then set text according to return value

Comment: @Van thank you but still i didnt get it yet

Comment: what you didn't get

Comment: I changed the code as u see but still the same , what I didn't get if the custom keyboard is there how I can make the limit work @Van

Comment: check with answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your bun action

```
@IBAction func Botton1(_ sender: UIButton) {

    textField1.text = textField1.text! + String (sender.tag)
}
```

change as

```
 @IBAction func Botton1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let range: NSRange = NSRange.init(location: 0, length: 1)
    if self.textField(textField1, shouldChangeCharactersIn: range, replacementString: String(sender.tag)) {
        textField1.text = textField1.text! + String (sender.tag)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you @Van but the code give me an error says (Cannot convert value of type 'CountableClosedRange<Int>' to expected argument type 'NSRange' (aka '_NSRange') )

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaank you @Van thank you for keep answering my silly questions tell u give me an answer it works great

Comment: my pleasure. happy to help